# entering dev_appserver.py on cmd line just opens the file. Does NOT run it

Tags: google-app-engine

On windows cmd line I am entering the following:
"dev_appserver.py" myapp

But, dev_appserver.py file just opens as a word doc.

Could you pls let me let me know why I am not able to run it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've manage to associate .py with Microsoft Word. This is a Windows thing, and not at all an App Engine thing.

To run dev_appserver.py, try

```
python dev_appserver.py
```

which assumes that you have python in your PATH.

Answer (score 0):

archlinux's terminal you should run the next command:

```
python2 /usr/bin/dev_appserver.py --clear_datastore yes app-id
```

Comment: The question is specifically about Windows.